# regular expression to match phone number but not zipcodes

Tags: python, regex

I have written below regex

```
phone_regex = re.compile(r'(\+?\(?\+?\d{1,}\)?[-\s\.]?\d{1,}[-\s\.]?\d{1,}[-\s\.]?\d{1,}[-\s\.]?\d{1,}[-s\.]?)')
```

It matches & identifies phone numbers along with country codes eg 
`+91 9561217616`,`(+91) 9561 217 616`,`+(91) 9561217616`,`+91-9833775049`
but it also match `431003` (zipcode) can someone help out to write regex to match only phones but not zipcodes

Comment: You could make the last number be more than 3 integers long. https://regex101.com/r/gV1qP8/1 `\d{3,}`, doesn't really require a phone number though. US zip codes with local code would match still.

Comment: In addition to @chris85 you should tidy up your regex since you're checking each digit individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?:\+\d\d|\(\+\d\d\)|\+\(\d\d\))(?:\s+|-)\d{4}(?:\s+|-)?\d{3}(?:\s+|-)?\d{3}$`

- `(?:\+\d\d|\(\+\d\d\)|\+\(\d\d\))` +00 or (+00) or +(00)
- `(?:\s+|-)` a gap (at least one space or a single dash)
- `\d{4}` 4 numbers (0000)
- `(?:\s+|-)?` an optional gap (at least one space or a single dash or -nothing at all)
- `\d{3}` 3 numbers (000)
- `(?:\s+|-)?` an optional gap
- `\d{3}` 3 numbers (000)

As a zip code won't fulfill all these requirements, it won't pass the regex.

Comment: its working but not getting country code,getting output as 9833775049 for input "Katraj, Pune 411037+91-9833775049" i wish it could be like +91-9833775049 or +919833775049

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean. Try removing the `^` and `$` characters from either end of the regex and let me know what that does.

Comment: i have removed all special charachters like whitespaces,commas,( &) using string method translate(None,"\s().,-_").replace(" ","")
& now using regex like (r'\+?\d{7,}') which is giving me output like +919833775049

Comment: Okay. I'm not really that clear on what you need, as it seems there is some information not included in the original post. Is that what you wanted? Is it all solved? Or do you need some specific help?

Comment: your answer is working ...getting o/p as 9833775049 for input          "Katraj, Pune 411037+91-9833775049"                                                          i wish it could be like +91-9833775049        or +919833775049

Comment: So it is _not_ working then? I'm getting the whole phone number from that input. I don't understand why you're not using the regex I provided in my answer in your code.

Comment: thanks @Whothehellisthat ,i was trying it for almost 1 hour

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify number of matches, e.g. `{m, n}` or `{m}` like:

```
regexp = r'''
# matches phones, but not zipcodes. Use with VERBOSE regexps
^     # start of the string
\s*?  # whitespaces, etc
\+?   # + char (optional)
\s*?  # whitespaces, etc
\(?   # ( char (optional)
([0-9]{3})   # 3 numbers
\)?   # ) char (optional)
(     # group start
  [\s-]?      # whitespace, - char (optionals)
  [0-9]       # 1 number
){7}  # matches exactly 7 numbers
\s*?  # whitespaces, etc
$     # end of the string
'''

phones = ['(123) 456 7899', '(123)-456-7899', '+1234567899', '+123 456-7899', 
          '12-34567899', '+123456789']  # these 2 dont match
matches = [bool(re.match(regexp, num, re.VERBOSE)) for num in phones]
print(matches)  # gives [True, True, True, True, False, False]
```

Working with VERBOSE regexps gives you a great debug